# How can I Send a Magento order to third-party API when placed

Tags: magento-1.9, php, api, xml

I'm trying to send sales orders to third-party API from magento website.once a customer submitted order should be call this API and if order cancel or reorder should be call this API. Is there way to do this in magento?

How and where will it get triggered?

Answer (score 1):

You should create custom extension with an observer for the `checkout_submit_all_after` event.

This event covers both front- and backend orders.

You can get your order object(s) like this in your observer:

```
if ($observer->getEvent()->hasOrders()) {

           $orders = $observer->getEvent()->getOrders();

       } else {

           $orders[] = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

       }

       foreach ($orders as $order) {
       //call here
       }
}
```